# How to get street names from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, shapefile, openstreetmap

I have some SHP layers that contain some streets and buildings data, and i'm showing it with openLayers (by GeoServer).
they are not contain the names of the streets or the numbers of the buildings.
there is a way to get from OSM list with the streets names and the numbers of buildings with the location of theme, its can be in any format(kml, shp, gml, text etc)?

Answer (score 3):

You can download roads and buildings from [overpass query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) and export in geojson, gpx, kml format.use the following query:

```
<osm-script>
    <union> 
        <query type="way"> 
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/> 
            <has-kv k="highway"/> 

        </query> 
        <query type="way">
          <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
          <has-kv k="building"/>    
        </query>
     <recurse type="way-node"/>
    </union> 
  <print mode="body"/>
</osm-script>
```

select the bounding box from the toolbar by clicking on "manaually select bbox" or it will take your current map view as bounding box of the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract data from OSM for a particular region but you cant get the name for your streets with a location query because they surely wont match perfectly.

See this question: [How can I extract data from OSM which includes the street names?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27533/how-can-i-extract-data-from-osm-which-includes-the-street-names) for information about OSM data extraction procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the OSM data as SHP from WeoGeo (my employer) for any location in the world. The streets/highways layer has names of streets and the buildings have numbers and type, when provided by the OSM user who created or edited the feature. You can also select the output to be any of the file formats you mentioned.

http://market.weogeo.com/datasets/osm-openstreetmap-planet.html

Comment: This service is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get shapefiles build from OSM data for most parts of the world from Geofabrik.
These contain street names, but not the number of buildings.

Furthermore, buildings are missing in Openstreetmap data for many (especially less populated) parts of the world.