# Polygons of countries including territorial waters

Tags: polygon, data, administrative-boundaries

Where can I get polygons (multipolygons) of all countries of the world including the territorial waters of the countries?

OpenStreetmap displays these areas but I can't find an extract of this subset of the OSM data.

- is there a subset of OSM data available, just containing the territories (incl. water territories) of a country as multipolygons ?
- or, can I find this set of polygons somewhere else?

Comment: I think you are looking for a way to download OSM. Look in this [thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27533/how-can-i-extract-data-from-osm-which-includes-the-street-names) or google it

Comment: OK, I was not detailed enough. I know that OSM has this data but I'm looking for an extract of the OSM data which just contains the boundaries of a country and the territorial waters. I do not want to download the complete world wide dataset just to get the boundaries. (changed the question accordingly)

Comment: try in http://www.geofabrik.de/, but I'm not sure they have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The country boundaries including the territorial waters are available in the OSM data set.
I found a site where these country shapes can be downloaded: 
https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/

Comment: Url is outdated, page moved to https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Global Administrative Areas dataset at http://www.gadm.org, it contains at least the boundaries, though I am not so sure about the territorial waters part